# Универсальный генерик-класс-враппер который декорируеет геттер/сеттер в зависимости от типа поля

Tags: c#

Допустим есть классы:

```
public class Skill: RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ShopItem : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

Можно ли написать некий универсальный генерик класс-"декоратор" который бы автоматически имел бы все проперти из перечисленных полей класса который я в него всуну, но в зависимости от типа поля по-разному их декорировал **(разным типам пропертей  выставлял разные Get; Set; методы)**

Важный момент: наследование для меня недопустимо.

То что я хотел бы получить выглядит приблизительно так:

```
Var decoratedSkill = new Decorator<Skill>(SkillInstance);
Var decoratedShopItem = new Decorator<ShopItem>(ShopItemInstance);


//decoratedSkill имеет все поля которые имеет Skill но обрабатывает каждое из них по некоему методу в зависимости от типа поля
// то есть есть обертка вокруг Геттера
// а есть обертка вокруг сеттера

decoratedSkill.Description = "hello";// вызовет метод Set обьекта decoratedSkill, сделает какие-то манипуляции и при этом вызовет set у SkillInstance в нужный момент.

//decoratedShopItem  имеет все поля которые имеет ShopItem но обрабатывает каждое из них по некоему методу в зависимости от типа поля
// то же самое
```

И да, наперед не известно какой класс я туда всуну.

Comment: в принципе можно посмотреть в сторону [ExpandoObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: или что то типа AOP, просто как пример на ум приходят перехватчики из Unity

Comment: @Grundy `ExpandoObject` похоже на то, что мне нужно. А можно ли в нем задавать геттер и сеттер для пропертей? А то в интернете не вижу ничего по этому поводу. Или прийдется каждую проперти разделять на `PropertyNameGet()` и `PropertyNameSet(SomeVarType value)`?

Comment: @Andrew, а не, я похоже перепутал с [`DynamicObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.dynamicobject?view=netframework-4.7.2) в документации пример есть с наследованием от него. Но вообще ExpandoObject реализует INotifyPropertyChanged и можно с этой стороны что-то подумать

Comment: Посмотрите пример: https://ideone.com/jIgQu0 Добавил декорацию для свойств, перед записью значения в свойство оно выводится на консоль. Не знаю, на сколько вы захотите такое использовать. Намешано всё: и рефлексия, и кодогенерация, и DLR

Comment: Спасибо за код. Поизучаю